# Ireport Interface Error

Tags: ireport, visual-glitch

I have some problem with my ireport interface, I don't know why my ireport interface have problem like this.

[image: Error Too.][image: InterfaceError]

I try to solve the problem with some step like reset window, install newest java 7 version but doesn't work.

Comment: I had some troubles (not interface, but it was  not loading jrxml correctly) to with launching the ireport.exe, switched to ireport_w.exe (always in the bin dir).. or just switch to JasperSoft Studio (since ireport is not really supported anymore)

Comment: i try that to open with ireport_w.exe first is fine but when i open the jrmxl file from ireport and click edit query the problem interface it's show again i don't know why.

Comment: Edit the query via jrxml : ), sorry I have no other solution...

Comment: problem solve with install jasperstudio